# Does Resharper contain a Convert to Direct Cast refactoring?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, resharper

I have code like this all over the code base:

```
MultiList ml = this.CriteriaList.ItemByName(SC_SAM_CATEGORIES) as MultiList;
```

I want to convert it to direct cast:

```
MultiList ml = (MultiList) this.CriteriaList.ItemByName(SC_SAM_CATEGORIES);
```

with a possible bonus of replacing `MultiList ml` with `var ml`.

Does Resharper contain a refactoring like this, perhaps via an addin?  If so, how do I turn it on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can actually compose your own refactorings through Custom Patterns : [see this link](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/08/highlighting-custom-patterns-with-resharper/)

In your case :

*Search pattern :*

```
$type$ $id$ = $expr$ as $type$;
```

*Replace pattern :*

```
var $id$ = ($type$) $expr$;
```

You can then make it appear as a quick-fix.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `$type1$ $id$ = $expr$ as $type1$;`, since it's the same type?

Comment: Note that you can use custom patterns to replace all the occurrences in your code base as well.

Comment: What if I just wanted to look for code like this: `this.CriteriaList.ItemByName(SC_SAM_CATEGORIES) as MultiList;` and convert that to `(MultiList) this.CriteriaList.ItemByName(SC_SAM_CATEGORIES);`?  I tried search pattern `$expr$ as $type$;`, but it doesn't find anything.