# How to create a custom pattern to replace `as` cast with direct cast in Resharper?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, resharper, resharper-7.1

I have a lot of code like this:

```
ml = this.CriteriaList.ItemByName(SC_STATIONS) as MultiList;
```

I'd like to replace it with

```
ml = (MultiList) this.CriteriaList.ItemByName(SC_STATIONS);
```

To that end, I went into Resharper Options, selected Custom Patterns and created a new one that has the following as the Search Pattern:

```
`$expr1$ as $type1$;`
```

with `expr1` meaning the expression and `type1` meaning type.  The replace pattern is `($type1$) $expr1$;`.

The problem is that Resharper never finds anything that matches this custom pattern.
What am I missing here?

Comment: does it **have** to be on ReSharper?

Comment: @AndreCalil It does not.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You are aware that the different syntaxes actually mean different things?

Comment: @AngryHacker This is a duplicate or rather a continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16471489/275751 which you asked earlier isn't it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: personally, I see code where the authors used the `as` syntax _instead of_ the `(type)` syntax without making use of the fact that `as` returns null if the cast would have failed. This means that when the cast _does_ fail, you just get a `NullReferenceException` some time later.

Comment: @PiersMyers Yes, I am trying to get it to the point where it works on all variations of the code base.

Comment: My point was that ReSharper should help tell you which situation you're in. If you use `as`, and then dereference it, ReSharper should warn you about a potential null reference exception. Likewise, if you use cast after `is`, ReSharper should tell you that you should use `as` instead. My point was that a global search-and-replace to remove `as` with a hard cast seems to focus on the wrong thing, that `as` is somehow unwanted. Perhaps for that particular code base it might be, but to be honest, I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, although it's not on ReSharper.

Open Visual Studio Replace window (CTRL + H), turn on the *Use regular expression* option and use the following terms:

- Find: `(.*)(\s|\((?!\))|\=)(.+) as (\w+)(\).*|;)`
- Replace: `$1$2($4)$3$5`

**Note**: if you're using VS2010, you should use `{}` instead of `()` and `\` instead of `$`. Go figure...

Comment: I am afraid, it doesn't really work, but I see the potential.  The following line: `Selected_AE = (this.CriteriaList.ItemByName(ReportCommon.CRITERIA_AES_VIERO) as MultiList).SelectedValues.Count;` gets converted into `Selected_AE = (MultiList).SelectedValues.Count) (this.CriteriaList.ItemByName(ReportCommon.CRITERIA_AES_VIERO);`

Comment: You will also find that it will match any strings or comments that contain 'as' and swap the words before and after it.

Comment: @PiersMyers Indeed, as long as the comment has the syntax `(anything) = (anything) as (anything);`, which is somewhat an awkward comment

Comment: @JohnSaunders Read my comment under the question

Comment: @AngryHacker Edited, could you try again?

Answer (score 1):

This Resharper Custom Pattern seems to do what you want:

[image]

The small program I used to test this pattern was:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var b = FooFactory() as bar;
        }

        static private foo FooFactory()
        {
            return new foo();
        }
    }

    class foo {}

    class bar : foo {}
}
```

and it should put a wiggly line under `FooFactory() as bar` offering you the option to replace it with `(bar)FooFactory()`

Adding `var ml = CriteriaList.ItemByName(SC_STATIONS) as MultiList;` and doing a 'Search Now' on  this custom pattern gives me this:

[image]

Comment: That is what I did.  Click save and then press Search button on the Custom Patterns dialog and see if anything is found.  My couldn't find anything.

Comment: @AngryHacker how odd, have you tried doing it as a 'Search with Pattern'? Are you sure you have c# selected? My test was done in VS2010 and Resharper 7.1.2

Comment: On my box it also finds simple expressions such as `var b = FooFactory() as bar`.  Try my example: `ml = this.CriteriaList.ItemByName(SC_STATIONS) as MultiList;`

Comment: that works for me too even without defining `CriteriaList`, `SC_STATIONS` or `MultiList`.